Ubuntu Boot Issue With 2 Monitors
I have two monitors. The main monitor that I want it to boot to is AOC and the side monitor is Samsung. When I turn on my computer I get a black screen on both monitors. I can get around this by unplugging the Samsung monitor before I boot the computer. Is there a setting in the bios that I need to change? I am using the onboard graphics card on my ASRock Z170 Extreme4 mother board. I'm running Ubuntu. How can I fix this?
I have a qemu graphics card passthrough. Maybe that's messing with something?
